# I cannot install SQL Server 2008 R2 express X64 management tools

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am trying to install the SQL Server 2008 R2 express X64 but it doesnot install the MANAGEMENT TOOLS because it finds the VS 2008 and it wants the SP1. I have not install any VS edition. How can I overcome this problem? I have windows 7 professional 64.

Thanks

Comment: Finally I found the: Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) with Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package. I downloaded and installed it and the installation of SQL server 2008 express finished succesfully.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps is it because Express comes in different editions. Not all them include the management tools.

Check the download page and choose the right version. The one you need is

> SQL Server 2008 Express with Tools

If you are sure you have the right download, perhaps you have installed earlier management tools and sql server considers that a kind of light VS? If you go to your installed programmes, do you see there any kind of SQL Server management tools (earlier version?) or VS?